# Отправка GET запроса на javascript

Tags: javascript, get, https, xmlhttprequest

такая проблема: мне нужно достать данные из sitemap.xml, но проблема в том, что код ниже работает только с моим сайтом. Если я подставлю любой другой адрес (Google для примера), то получаю ошибку: NetworkError: A network error occurred. Вот сам код:

```js
let url = new URL('https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml')
    const xml = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
    xml.open("GET", url, false)
    xml.send(null);
    alert(xml.responseText)
```

Comment: проблема в `CORS`, если посмотришь ошибки в консоли увидишь что-то вроде _Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, у меня получилось так:

```js
let url = new URL('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.google.com/sitemap.xml')
    const xml = new window.XMLHttpRequest()
    xml.open("GET", url, false)
    xml.send(null);
    alert(xml.responseText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Про CORS слышали когда то? Это политика регулировки того как один сайт может предоставлять доступ к данным при запросах от других сайтов. Удаленный сервер должен предварительно разрешить принимать и обрабатывать те или иные запросы. Обойти CORS не возможно, это безопасность.

Comment: А иного варианта реализации нет? Потому что если я просто в окне браузера нашу, то все нормально выдаст. Может есть костыльный способ напрямую как-то ввести ссылку без запросов

Comment: Если побыть занудой, то CORS все-таки не _политика_, а легальный _механизм обхода_ той самой [политики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)